# Create folders in hierarchy in s3 using lambda-python

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

In my project i'm trying to create hierarchy of folders in s3 via lambda python based on the last modified date. For example the last modified date is jun/04/2022. I need to create hierarchy of folders in s3 like year->month->date.
Example:jun/04/2022. The created folders should be in the below hierarchy,
->2022
-jun
-jun/04/2022
How to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood, but I think that you want to save your files with the key year/month/day/filename.extension. When you access s3, you'll see your files inside that hierarchy.

Comment: yes, what u understood was correct.

Comment: So all you need to do is save your files with the hierarchy you need as the key ;)

Comment: yes, is there any way to create folder (keys) in such order.

Comment: S3 is a flat storage service. There aren't really folders. `year/month/day/filename.extension` is just the "key" or "name" of the object you are saving. There really aren't any folders there. The S3 UI lets you browse "folders" by simply looking for `/` characters in the names of your S3 objects. All this is to say, just specify those folders as you are saving your actual files in S3, and then they will be there. You don't need to create anything ahead of time.